# Zypper: How do I display all packages from a certain repository?

Tags: linux, command-line, package-management, rpm, zypper

Please tell me, how to let zypper display all **installed** packages of a certain repository.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can easily list that using:

```
zypper pa -ir <repo_name_or_number>
```

Comment: Thanks! It works for me only with capital `R` Please correct the answer.

Comment: The capital R is for sorting by repo. The lower case one is for the specific repo.

You can check the documentation by typing:

    zypper pa -h

Comment: Sorry, I must have typed it just the wrong way at first time. Indeed, `r` works.

Comment: Doesn't work for me using zypper 1.11.22 on OpenSUSE 13.2. Better use `zypper search` like suggested on the other answer.

Comment: For zypper 1.14.45 on OpenSUSE 15.2 this shows the packages already installed that **could** be installed from that repo, independently that they were actually installed from that repo, or from any other. `zypper search -i -r` answer below does indeed shows **only** installed packages from that repo.

Comment: This answer is flat out incorrect. See the previous comment. The pa command literally means "packages available". The other answer here is correct.

Answer (score 17):

Alternative:

```
zypper search -i -r <repo alias|#|URI>
```

Comment: For zypper 1.14.45 on OpenSUSE 15.2 this is the correct answer.

Answer (score -1):

To find the repo of a package

```
zypper se -v <package_name>
```