# Searching for packages that are (not) from a certain repository URL

Tags: debian, aptitude, packages, repository, apt

I basically want to do the same thing, as [asked for here](https://superuser.com/questions/132346/find-packages-installed-from-a-certain-repository-with-aptitude), which is searching for packages that a re not from a certain repository. Just like this:

```
aptitude search "?installed?not(?origin(Debian))"
```

However, I want to provide a specific repository, because for example the packages from http://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org can not be found with the command above.